# Issues installing driver(s) for Canon MF212w

Tags: drivers, 16.04, printing, canon

Just acquired a Canon Imageclass MF212w printer because they provide an official driver at their website. Running Xenial on a 64 bit machines.

Downloaded it, started the install and got this:

OK: libglade2-0

OK: libstdc++6:i386

OK: libxml2:i386

NG: libjpeg62:i386

NG: libbeecrypt7:i386

NG: libbeecrypt-dev:i386

Downloaded libjpeg62, installed libbeecrypt7 (was: libbeecrypt7_4.2.1-4_amd64), and I think I got libbeecrypt installed too.

Tried to install the official driver again, still says the last three items are "NG", but proceeded since I'm using amd64 rather than i386. Driver's installed, AFAIK, and it's connected to my router.

When I open the print dialog, I'll get "rejecting jobs" but if I click on that printer then I'll get "Getting printer information..." but it just hangs.

How can I get my printer to print?

Answer (score 2):

just go in /Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_us_EN/64-bit_Driver/RPM and do

> su root
>
> dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_3.60-1_amd64.deb
>
> dpkg -i cndrvcups-ufr2-us_3.20-1_amd64.deb
>
> service cups restart

then search and add the printer from the system GUI.